# How to get details of Deleted rpms

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild

I had some rpms which was build locally using rpm-build.I installed it on CentOS machine and later i removed and installed latest build ones. Now i am in a situation to get the previous installed rpm version. Is there any way to get the list of removed rpms??. I removed the previous rpms using "rpm -e" command.

Answer (score 0):

Older versions stored a snapshot of the installed RPMs in `/var/log/rpmpkgs` - I don't remember what interval, but it's not built-in; it was a cron job. Newer distributions don't seem to do that any more, because `yum` logs everything natively, and the cron job was kind of a hack.

You don't say what version of CentOS, but if you don't have that log file, I think you're out of luck. You might get lucky and have it in somebody's shell history (root or a user who ran `sudo`).